# How to check what kind of saving it is?

Tags: hooks, save-post

I use `save_post` hook, and I have to know inside this hook function, whether it is a publishing ( `draft to publish` ) or is it an updating, like `publish to publish` or `draft to draft`.

Is there a way to check it?

I can not use `draft_to_publish` hook for this, and I'll explain why:
The users ask questions on the site, and questions are saved as `draft` posts. A site admin write an answer and then publish the post. A post has `meta box` "status" that can have next values: "not answered", "treatment", "answered". A site admin may change this value as he wants, but when he publish the post (draft to publish, or draft to private), this meta value must be changed automatically to "answered" (although that the `input area` on admin area has another value). So I have a function that fired on `save_post` hook, that save all values according to `input area` values. And also I tried to use `draft_to_publish` hook to assign "answered" to the meta value. The problem is that `save_post` always fired after `draft_to_publish`, so that the value ("answered" that assigned on `draft_to_publish`) is overridden by the value of `input area`.

Comment: I decided to use `global variable`. I assign `$is_publishing_now = true` in `draft_to_publish` hook, and by this way can know during `save_post` hook, that it is publishing now. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hooks specifically for this, actually. The codex [has a pretty good overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

Essentially every time WordPress saves a post (which it does through `wp_insert_post`) or alters the status of the post, it calls `wp_transition_post_status` which looks like this:

```
<?php
// in wp-includes/post.php
function wp_transition_post_status($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    do_action('transition_post_status', $new_status, $old_status, $post);
    do_action("{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}", $post);
    do_action("{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post);
}
```

So, if  you want to check for a post moving from publish to publish you could do this...

```
<?php
add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse83835_transition', 10, 3);
function wpse83835_transition($new, $old, $post)
{
    if ('publish' == $new && 'publish' == $old) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Or this...

```
<?php
add_action('publish_to_publish', 'wpse83835_transition_again');
function wpse83835_transition_again($post)
{
    // do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But seems that I can not use this hook. I edited the question to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another hook to define action on update. The **post_updated** hook is defined as this:

```
do_action( 'post_updated', $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before);
```

and is not called on post creation. variable $update is set as follows:

```
   // Are we updating or creating?
    if ( !empty($ID) ) {
        $update = true;
        $post_ID = (int) $ID;
    } else {
        $update = false;
        $post_ID = 0;
    }
```

And hook posts_updated is inside following if statement:

```
if ( $update ) {
        do_action('edit_post', $post_ID, $post);
        $post_after = get_post($post_ID);
        do_action( 'post_updated', $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before);
    }

    do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
    do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

to check if it is draft to publish, you'll check on $post_before->post_status and on $post_after->post_status.

Just as an addendum here is a check for ommit autosave:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;
```

Comment: Apparently that did not suit me. I edited the question to explain more.